# Are there any sample templates for product grids websites?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anyone know of any websites that offer sample html templates of product/image grids in a ecommerce website, which is easy to manipulate, so it's something to my appeal. Right now, I'm not really looking to pay for anything, but just the whole product grid is what I am really looking for, I have everything else.

Something similar to this: http://www.stellamccartney.com/us/stella-mccartney/women/tops/

There's no code, I just want some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are TONS of site templates out there. If you're willing to pay a very little amount, like < $50, you can get a fully baked template on sites such as [Theme Forest](http://themeforest.net/). It is an unbelievably good deal if you find one you like.

Otherwise, take a look at some of the free templates for [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) or [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/). You can roll your own or find free templates for these frameworks as well. Good luck